# HTML5, JS, image annotations on iOS phonegap app

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, html5-canvas, phonegap-plugins

is it possible to actually achieve a HTML5, CSS3 and JS based image annotation tool in a phonegap app for ios or any other platform, so that the captured image (via camera) can be annotated with some text and lines? If so, please suggest a possible approach/open source libraries that can be of help.

As of now we are only thinking of playing around with the canvas element.

Answer (score 0):

a simple library is http://intridea.github.io/sketch.js/

it uses canvas, allows you to draw over an image, it warns that there might be degragation on mobile devices, currently trying this out, so can't verify it yet.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion will look in to it. I tried Kinetic JS. It serves most of the purposes. Had a little problem though which i have explained here:-http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22837585/kineticjs-image-annotation-tool-accross-devices